# Compare previous and next values when looping through a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, comparison, enumerate

I should compare the previous, actual and next values in a list.
This lines of code here underneath doesn't fully works.

The results of the code are:

```
5 4 6
8 10 11
20 18 19
```

so I miss values like

```
9 8 10
```

and values like

```
8 10 11
```

are simply wrong.

What am I missing in the `enumerate` method?

```
list=[1,2,3,4,5,4,6,7,9,8,10,11,14,15,16,20,18,19]

for i,n in enumerate (list):

    if (i + 1 < len( list ) and i - 1 >= 0):

        a = str( list[i - 1] )
        b = str( n )
        c = str( list[i + 1] )

        if a>b<c:
            print (a,b,c)
```

Comment: Use: `a>b and b < c` and why do you need to convert them from int to str?

Comment: Don't call your lists `list` because that makes them hide python's inbuilt `list` class

Answer (score 2):

After the `str` conversion, it holds that "10" < "8" because strings are compared lexicographically. So you can simply omit those:

```
a = list[i - 1]
b = n 
c = list[i + 1]
```

You could also use `zip` with 1-offset slices to simplify this sort of "iterate neighbors" pattern:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,4,6,7,9,8,10,11,14,15,16,20,18,19]  # don't shadow built-in `list`
for a, b, c in zip(lst, lst[1:], lst[2:]):
    if a > b < c:
        print(a,b,c)

5 4 6
9 8 10
20 18 19
```

Comment: Thanks Schwobaseggl, interesting use of zip function, where can i find more info about this uses of zip?Regards